# Lombok two nullable values but one must be present

Tags: java, nullable, lombok, builder

Given the following object

```
@Getter
@Builder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Example {
    private final String maybeA;
    private final String maybeB;
}
```

Is it possible to add a constraint where one of these fields has to exist?

So we can have A and B, A or B, but not A nor B.

Comment: Can both exist? Or must *exactly* one be non-null? If it's the latter, you're probably looking for a sealed class with two subclasses for the two cases. If both can exist but at least one must, then I don't think Lombok can help you and you'll just need to have an explicit check in your constructor.

Comment: If I solved this problem in the language with another type system, I would determine the type that meets your requirements, and would use one field of this type instead of two `String maybe_`. I'm not sure that this approach is possible in Java

Comment: @SilvioMayolo yes both can exist. That's a shame it's probably not possible. But thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@AssertFalse`, an annotation of the package `javax.validation.constraints` :

```
@Getter
@Builder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Example {
    private final String maybeA;
    private final String maybeB;

    @AssertFalse
    private boolean oneFieldHasToExists() {
        return maybeA == null && maybeB == null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
@Getter
class Example {
    private final String maybeA;
    private final String maybeB;

    @Builder
    public Example(String maybeA, String maybeB) {
       if (maybeA == null && maybeB == null) {
          throw IllegalArgumentException("...");
       }
       this.maybeA = maybeA;
       this.maybeB = maybeB;
    }
}
```